# Make SharePoint List Item accessible to users with links only

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, list-item

I want users to be able to see SharePoint list item which have they link, I do not want them to see list items they don't have direct link. Just like the one below in google drive. Please let me know if this is possible and how to achieve. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using SharePoint Online. Please let me know if you are in a different environment.

For only allowing users to access list item via direct links, I will suggest you to give **no** permission level for these users in list level, and only provide them with a sharing link to the specific list item. They can use the link to access the list item however they have no permission to see other items.

**Basic idea of SharePoint Permissions:**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-experience-sharing-permissions

**Customize Permissions for a list:**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782

**How to share a file or folder:**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-sharepoint-files-or-folders-1fe37332-0f9a-4719-970e-d2578da4941c

Comment: Hi Jerry, thank you for responding.

I have followed the links you provided. I update the policy of the site on the SharePoint admin center to the below:

External Sharing
-Anyone (Advanced setting - Limit sharing by domain is unchecked).

Default Sharing Link Type
-Anyone with link (Expiration of anyone links - These links never expire)

Default Link Permission
-View

When I share a list item or copy link, the option Anyone with link and People in [Name] with link is both disabled.

May I know where did I missed?

Comment: The goal is for anyone outside organization to see the "attachment"/image (the out of the box of SharePoint online) once attachment url is given to them.

Thanks in advance for the help.